# Func<T> injecting with Windsor container

Tags: delegates, castle-windsor

Here is a code excerpt from AspComet project that works with Autofac.

```
public MessageBus(IClientRepository clientRepository, Func<IMessagesProcessor> messagesProcessorFactoryMethod)
{
    this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    this.messagesProcessorFactoryMethod = messagesProcessorFactoryMethod;
}
```

How can I inject "`Func<IMessagesProcessor> messagesProcessorFactoryMethod`" with Windsor, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
container.Register(Component.For<Func<Foo>>().Instance(f));
```

Here's a passing unit test that demonstrates the concept:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    Func<string> f = () => "Hello world";

    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<Func<string>>().Instance(f));

    var resolvedFunc = container.Resolve<Func<string>>();

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello world", f());
}
```

Comment: It works as you suggested but I had to return IMessagesProcessor from the container so I coded it like this: 

Func<IMessagesProcessor> messagesProcessorFactoryMethod = () => container.Resolve<IMessagesProcessor>();

Is there a better way or this is the best way?

Comment: You can get Autofac-like behavior with no additional work by using the following custom facility: http://www.assembla.com/code/kkozmic/subversion/nodes/Garage/Castle.LightweightFactoryFacility

If you don't want to use the facility, the solution you outlined in the previous comment is the way to go.

Comment: As of trunk (and starting with upcoming version 2.5) this behavior is baked in, that is you won't have to register the `Func` explicitly. Just having the constructor will be enough for Windsor to figure out what to do, and it will provide the delegate itself.

Answer (score 7):

```
Container.Register(
  Component.For<IMessagesProcessor>()
           .ImplementedBy<MessagesProcessor>()
           .Lifetime.Transient,
  Component.For<Func<IMessagesProcessor>>()
           .Instance(() => Container.Resolve<IMessagesProcessor>())
)
```

That should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Castle.Windsor 2.5+ comes with [delegate-based factories](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-delegate-based.md) support which allows it to resolve a delegate for you without any explicit registration.