# Dependency Injection with repository "Generator"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I did my research and I can’t find any specific example of what I want to do.

I successfully implement Ninject into me MVC project. Everything works perfect. However, I want to do a last step.

Until now, I have been working like this (normal DI pattern):

```
public class myController : Controller
{  
    private iMyInterface myRepository;

    public myController(iMyInterface myRepository)
    {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }        

    public ActionResult list(){
        return view(myRepository.getMyList())
    }        

    // rest o the code ...
}
```

My Question is; there is a way to do something like this? (Repository “Generator”)

```
public class myController : Controller
{  
    private iMyInterface myRepository = specialClass.GetMyRepository();

    public ActionResult list(){
        return view(myRepository.getMyList()) }

    // rest o the code ...    
}
```

I aware I’m writing a nonsense code, but the idea is to be able to do something similar.

Any recommendation?

Comment: What's the intension behind this? Your current solution seems to be ok. So why changing to a service locator like design?

Comment: Your first example would be far easier to unit test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what `specialClass` is supposed to be, but this looks a lot like the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) in action.

The **first option** where the repository is injected through the constructor **is better**, because it gives you more options, *including* using `specialClass`:

```
var controller = new myController(specialClass.GetMyRepository());
```

I don't know Ninject, but most DI Containers give you an option to map an interface to a method call that returns an instance of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather take a repository "Generator" in a constructor. That would give you the same result, but with a correct injection.

Comment: No, that would be a Leaky Abstraction. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648318/dependency-injection-new-instance-required-in-several-of-a-classes-methods/4650050#4650050 for an similar question and an explanation for why it would be a leaky abstraction.

Comment: Personally I prefer classic dependency injection approach http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html