# Dependency Injection Repository Lifetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm not sure the specific implementation is important here but for completeness I'm using Autofac as my dependency injection container for a new application.

All my repositories depend on a `DbContext` (unit of work) which I have used the MVC3 integration library to configure as `InstancePerHttpRequest()` so that the unit of work is shared between repositories for each request.

I've looked at some applications that use Autofac and I have noticed that they're setting the lifetime of their repositories as `SingleInstance()` (singleton). Is this correct?

The reason I ask is that I can understand that we don't really need multiple repository classes but if we're creating a single instance of a repository then that surely means that there is only one reference to a `DbContext`. In my repository implementation it accesses the `DbContext` as a class member e.g. `_dbContext.Set<T>` blah....

So `_dbContext` must have a reference to some object in memory. How is it possible for two separate requests to come along, have a unique `DbContext` but share the same repository?

Have I missed something to do with the way DI works?

Comment: It mostly sounds like a misconfiguration of lifetimes, because I can certainly understand why you ask. However, in theory, it's possible to make it work using this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648318/dependency-injection-new-instance-required-in-several-of-a-classes-methods/4650050#4650050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't missed anything - `SingleInstance()` is almost certainly the wrong choice for repositories in your scenario.